# Show that $\cos$ has at least one zeropoint

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, proof-explanation

Suppose $\cos$ has no zeropoints then all values of $\cos$ must be positive due to the fact that $\cos$ is continuous,  on $(-\infty,+\infty)$ and $\cos(0)=1$ and $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$ ,

one could choose any closed intervall $[a,b]$ with $a,b\geq 0$ and assume the opposite that it $\cos(b)$ is negative. The intermediate value Theorem then would say that there must exist a zeropoint.

$(\sin x)'= \cos x$, now because of the Mean Value Theorem and the fact that $\cos>0$. $\sin$ must be strictly rising.

I.e $a_1<x\Longrightarrow \sin a_1< \sin x$

Therefore

$a_1<x\Longrightarrow -\sin a_1>-\sin x$

Because of the fact that $\sin 0 = 0 = -\sin 0 $ and $-\sin x= (\cos x)'$

$(\cos x)'= (-\sin x)\leq (\cos a)' = (-\sin a) < (\cos 0)'=(-\sin 0) = 0$ for $0<a\leq x$

---

**Here is the part now that I don't understand**

Why do the Facts so far implicate?

$\cos x\leq \cos a - (x-a)\sin a, \text{(where }\sin a > 0 $ and again for $0<a\leq x\text{)}$

And how does one conclude by that?

$\cos x \rightarrow -\infty$ for $x\rightarrow+\infty$

---

I understand the last conclusion that if above is true

then it would be a contradiction to $|\cos|\leq 1$ (which we have proved earlier)

Therefore $\cos$ would have at least one zeropoint

Comment: What is your definition of $\cos$ ? Or at least the properties we can consider. It is essential to know what we can exploit, else this will be kind of self-referent proof.

Comment: we have defined $\cos x :=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$ But so far we are only putting real numbers in the function, i.e $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: More precisely, if you're using the intermediate value theorem, you must first be sure that the cosine gives _real_ results when the input value is real. This is not quite obvious from the definition you're quoting.

Comment: See for reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3086426/is-0-infty-closed-and-can-the-intermediate-value-theorem-can-be-applied-to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proved that $x\geqslant a\implies\cos'x\leqslant-\sin a$. Now, let $f(x)=\cos(a)-(x-a)\sin(a)$. Then:

- $f(a)=\cos(a)$;
- $x\geqslant a\implies f'(x)=-\sin(a)\geqslant\cos'(x)$.

But then $(\forall x\in[a,\infty]):f(x)\geqslant\cos(x)$. So, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\cos(x)=-\infty$.

Comment: Why is $f'(x)=-\sin a$ ?

Comment: If $F(x)=\alpha+\beta x$, $F'(x)=\beta$.

Comment: Why $-\sin(a)\geq\cos'(x),\forall x\geq a$ implicate $f(x)\geq \cos(x),\forall x\geq a$ and why $\cos(a)$ cannot be $+\infty $ i.e why $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=-\infty
$?

Comment: If you have two differentiable functions $G$ and $H$ with $G(a)=H(a)$ and $(\forall x\in[a,\infty)):G'(x)\geqslant H'(x)$, then $(\forall x\in[a,\infty)):G(x)\geqslant H(x)$. And $\cos$ is a real function; therefore $\cos(a)$ is a real number, and $+\infty$ is not a real number.

Comment: But because $F(x)$ and $cos(x)$ are complex valued I have to consider the absolute value